# Rails 4: User admin field in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku, devise

I am using `Devise` to handle my users and I have a field for `admin` which defaults to `false`.

In order to access certain pages, `current_user.admin` needs to be `true`.

When I run `rails c -e=production` and view the attributes for my `User`, I see `admin: true`, but I cannot access the pages only available to admins.  In my controller when I print `current_user.admin` to the console and my heroku logs show `false`.

**Is there any reason why the console attributes and the attributes on the heroku site would be different?  Should I handle this differently?**

Comment: Both your production console and Heroku site are connecting to the same DB? Does `current_user.id` equal the `id` of the user in the Rails console?

Comment: yes!  I really dont understand how this could be happening

Comment: I must be connecting to a different database, but how can I check that?

Comment: When I purposely edit my `database.yml` for production, my connection still goes through in the console without any problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging I came across this [article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior#rails-4-1-and-beyond) that goes into the details of the `database.yml` and how the values set for a variety of variables will have no effect.

I think connected to the heroku database through `heroku run console` and was able to see my `User` and correct the `admin` field.

Hope this helps someone else who may run into a similar issue